# How to get attribute name instead of slug in variation?

Tags: php, variables, attributes, woocommerce, slug

I need to get attribute from woocommerce product variation.

```
$terms = get_post_meta($value['variation_id'], 'attribute_pa_color', true);
```

This code is giving me an attribute slug instead of name. How can I get attribute name?

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What you are getting is the slug of a taxonomy...
In WooCommerce, `attribute_pa_color` without the `attribute_` is a taxonomy.

So you can try something like this.. to get the term by slug. And get it's name.

```
$taxonomy = 'pa_color';
$meta = get_post_meta($value['variation_id'], 'attribute_'.$taxonomy, true);
$term = get_term_by('slug', $meta, $taxonomy);
echo $term->name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Native WooCommerce function wc_attribute_label() is the easiest way for this task.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find attributes by below code

```
 foreach ($product->attributes as $taxonomy => $attribute) {
   foreach ($attribute->get_terms() as $term) {
      var_dump($term); // term object data
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to display the attributes of an added product in the cart and this is how I did it. I hope it will be useful to someone

```
<?foreach ($cart_item['variation'] as $name => $value) :
    $attribute_label = wc_attribute_label(str_replace('attribute_', '', urldecode($name)), $_product);
    $attribute_value = $_product->get_attribute(str_replace('attribute_', '', urldecode($name))); 
?>
    <span>
        <?echo $attribute_label . ':&nbsp;' . $attribute_value ?>
    </span>
<?endforeach; ?>
```

Please note that on the cart page there is usually `$_product`, on another page you may need to remove the underscore `$product`. Also, on another page you will most likely receive a slug without the `attribute_` prefix. There it will be enough to indicate `$attribute_name` (for example it will be `'pa_color'`) - `$attribute_label = wc_attribute_label($attribute_name, $product);`

The name and value of the attributes were in Cyrillic, which led to some problems because I received transliterated values. I had to do reverse transliteration, which I think is not a very correct way. And only now I came to this decision.
I don’t know how correct and adequate this is, but it works

Answer (score -1):

You can try the following code.

```
$terms = get_the_terms( $value['variation_id'] , 'attribute_pa_color');

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    echo $term->name;
}
```

Let me know if that helped. Additional you can go through the explanation given in [this](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/display-custom-attributes-on-description-tab-of-single-product-page) link for more information and alternative solutions.

Comment: Not working, but I'll try to do sth about it. Thanks for hint!

Comment: It works with this: get_the_terms( $product->id , 'pa_color'); but it returns attributes from all variations :(

Comment: Tried to hard code variation ID instead of product ID and its not working. My guess is it is not supposed to be used this way (with variation ID)?