# By a variable product id, how to display variations products by their specified SKUs

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations, variable-product

I want to display some variations products by their specified skus and not to display all the variations products within a variable product id.

**For example:**
The Variable product id is: #556

- Sub variations products of variable product id #556, I want it to display variations products on index-page by their specified skus to display image, title and link to the variable product id #556 page.

My code below is working, but it is showing each and every variations of the products within the variable product id 556. I need to be selective by which, variations products to show by their specified skus to display image, title and link.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 
$product = new WC_Product_Variable( '556' ); 
$variations = $product->get_available_variations(); 

foreach ( $product->get_variation_attributes() as $attribute_name => $attribute ) { 
    $attributes[] = array( 'term_name' => ucwords( str_replace( 'attribute_', '', 
    wc_attribute_taxonomy_slug( $attribute_name ) ) ), 'option' => $attribute, ); 
} 

foreach ( $variations as $variation ) { 
    echo '<div class="index_main_products col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">';
    echo '<a href="'.$product->get_permalink().'#variations-table">';
    echo "<img src=" . $variation['image']['thumb_src'] .">";
    echo '</a>';

    echo '<h2>';
    echo implode(str_replace('_', ' ',  $variation['attributes']));
    echo '</h2>';

    echo '<a class="index_button button" href="'.$product->get_permalink().'">View Product</a>';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Please if you could help. Been trying for soo long and nothing seems to be working.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by **initializing an array of product variation skus** that you don't want to see.

Then in the loop you can check **if the current variation sku is present in the array**. If yes, do not display it and continue to the next product.

```
$product = new WC_Product_Variable( 556 );
// initializes an array with product variation skus not to be displayed
$skus = array( 'sku-1', 'sku-2', 'sku-3' );
$variations = $product->get_available_variations(); 

foreach ( $product->get_variation_attributes() as $attribute_name => $attribute ) { 
    $attributes[] = array( 'term_name' => ucwords( str_replace( 'attribute_', '', wc_attribute_taxonomy_slug( $attribute_name ) ) ), 'option' => $attribute, ); 
} 

foreach ( $variations as $variation ) { 
    // if the sku of the product variation is not in the array it continues to the next variation
    if ( ! in_array( $variation['sku'], $skus ) ) {
        continue;
    }
    // otherwise
    echo '<div class="index_main_products col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3">';
    echo '<a href="'.$product->get_permalink().'#variations-table">';
    echo "<img src=" . $variation['image']['thumb_src'] .">";
    echo '</a>';
    echo '<h2>';
    echo implode(str_replace('_', ' ',  $variation['attributes']));
    echo '</h2>';
    echo '<a class="index_button button" href="'.$product->get_permalink().'">View Product</a>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

*The code could not be tested but it should work.*

Comment: Thank you soo much for your help, this works as intended.

Comment: Can I please ask one question? How can I get the attributes? For eg: I have attribute set for this variations product and want to display attribute by 'slug-name' which is 'voltage'. Is it possible to do so? Thank you once again for your great help. Have a great day.

Comment: With `$variation['attributes']` you get an array with all the attributes of the product variation. If you want to get only the attribute values with slug **voltage** you can use `$variation['attributes']['attribute_pa_voltage']`. This way you get the slug (or slugs) of the variation attribute. To get the name from the attribute term slug look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35130013/how-to-get-attribute-name-instead-of-slug-in-variation).

Comment: Thank you soo much for the information. This resolved my issue and have a great day :)